# Getting the band together — lighting in discord

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

In an amateur band it was impossible to get everyone together at once for a dress rehearsal.  Different people are traveling (usually out of the country) at any one time, and they often practice in someone's home or a rented space (not a stage), and etc.

Someone thought it would be suitable to simply add some people to the old photograph.  Thinking it was like one or two substitutions, and that I'd photograph the people myself under open shade with an eye to matching, I agreed.

As it turns out, the new photos submitted were taken with a good camera and lens, but saved as in-camera JPEGs.  (Rant: if the gear cost more than 2 grand, JPEG should be disabled as an option.)  The stage lighting is rather severe.  Meanwhile, the “old” photo from last year's poster was only saved as JPEG too!  It used a fill flash and got very flat lighting, but the stage lighting affected the white balance.

Here is an initial paste-up:

[image: draft paste-up]
[image: draft detail]

The full file (PSD with layers) is [On Adobe CC](http://adobe.ly/1guqtlp).

Now I can handle the masking and all that.

I want some advice on matching the lighting.  How can I get the contrasty faces to better match the flat lighting?

Second, what about color matching for the uniforms?  The Hue Range sliders are not helpful in a simple use of that adjustment layer.

As shown, I reduced the contrast and shifted the color space of the high-key assets using “ACR as a (smart) filter”.  The original can be seen in the PSD file.

The poster from last year had the picture printed 8″ wide.  Since the picture is wider now, they might print wider too, and **the paper is 11″ wide** so that's the expected size.  It won't be viewed from close up really.

Comment: Concerts must be interesting if the band members are never in the same place at the same time.

Comment: Various combinations or sometimes small groups are at any given performance.  [This](https://youtu.be/eJinaOSxNME?list=PLQkSJHxhFx-OiC0WHnp376x4qCaq8XbAr) was a small chamber orchestra, for example.  Explore the playlist.

Comment: @dpollitt - I have to agree with you on that one, even sticking in post I can think of half a dozen ways to deal with the issues in Photoshop.  As a hint though, most of the options I'd head for in post would be in the Lab colour space where I can split colour and contrast.

Comment: @dpollitt That is not helpful. The need to do it in post was presupposed, so saying "too bad you can't reshoot" is a non-answer.  Saying "Sure I know some techniques but I won't teach you and neither will anyone else 'cause it's hard" is actually condescending and the very opposite of helpful. Don't forget that an answer doesn't have to be a unique tutorial written for the purpose: it can be hints, brief suggestions of things to try (without blow-by-blow), or pointers to lessons already published somewhere.  Note...

Comment: Note that the recent question on purple lighting got answers including some basics, *not* snotty retorts about *should have used a flash, bummer* or *well I could, but it's too much work to explain.*  the latter should just be left unsaid by everyone who passes on any question that he *knows* but chooses not to address now.

Comment: You need to relax man.

Comment: Did I mention that my wife is in the band?